# Check if player is stationary for more than 3 seconds and then do something Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've started using Unity and I'm making my first platformer game. I want to add a feature where if a player stops moving (on the horizontal axis) for 3 seconds, he dies and the game restarts.

For the first part (checking if player is moving), I simply do this:

```
if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) == 0)
    {
        Example();
    }
```

I'm not sure where to place this code and I need help to implement the "wait for 3 seconds" part. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the time part like this. `Time.deltaTime`gives you time passed for that particular frame. As long as your player does not move you add to your timer.

```
float timePassed = 0.0f;

if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) == 0)
{
    Example();
    timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
}
else
    timePassed = 0.0f;
```

Then when your timer is bigger than 3 sec you can kill your player. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, the "Time.deltaTime" thing is exactly what I needed!